# How to get app "bytes in all heaps" performance counter from code, in run time?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, memory-leaks, performancecounter

I am trying to get specific app, "bytes in all heaps" performance counter,in run time.
The counter category is ".NET CLR Memory"
The Instance of the app presented in the performance counter window (see attachment).
But when a I am Trying to get the value from c# code with the Object PerformanceCounter, I get an error: "Instance  does not exist in the specified Category".

my code:

```
PerformanceCounter performaceCounter = new PerformanceCounter(".NET CLR Memory"
    , "# Bytes in all Heaps"
    , instanceName: "my app instance name"
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on my test, I can run the code about PerformanceCounter successfully.

Try to use `Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName` to replace your `instance name`.

You can refer to the following code.

```
  private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        PerformanceCounter PC = new PerformanceCounter(".NET CLR Memory", "# Bytes in all heaps", Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName);
        MessageBox.Show(PC.NextValue().ToString());
    }
```

I get some information from this instance about NextValue.

[image]